How to Show the History Details of Oracle Apex Application Changes?
Are there any way to show the details of changes during the development process of page components on oracle apex. I see the Monitor Activity feature but it not shown details like the report source changed, SQL Query of rows returned in Server Side Condition and HTML Expression of Column Formating attributes and Javascript Code of Action and so on.

There is no "development history" capture in APEX. APEX consist of a set of metadata and an application is just a large SQL script (or a set of individual sql scripts). A "version" of an application is just another "version of the sql script". The only way to keep history of an application is to export the application at regular intervals (this can probably be automated) and check it into a source control system. If the export is done using the "split" option (this is a parameter in sqlcl) then the history of the invididual pages/shared components can be tracked. This is also described in the APEX Application Development Lifecycle Technical Paper 
